# .Net Core - Analyzers - CA#### not appearing in Errors list

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

To replicate on VS 2017 Enterprise:

- Create new .Net Core solution with a Console App project
- Add the following NuGet Packages:

  - FxCop Analyzers 1.1.0
  - StyleCop Analyzers 1.0.2
  - Desktop.Analyzers 1.1.0
  - System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.Analyzers 1.1.0
- Create an interface that doesn't begin with an I
- Unload and reload project (just in case)
- Press Alt + F11 to run code analysis
- View Error List pane

A violation of the rule CA1715 "Interface names should be prefixed with 'I'" should appear on the Error List (because the effective severity for this rule is set to "warning" by default), but it doesn't (although it does appear in intellisense).

Does anyone know how to get these violations to appear as build warnings?

(I have also tried with the latest pre-release versions of all mentioned analyzers, and cannot get it to work with them either)

Comment: Analyzers can post any message - error, warning or informational. Have you enabled all of them? Perhaps you've only clicked on `Errors`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nope I have them all enabled. I can see all of the SA#### warnings that are there.